# Showing content of div depending on selection in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems with some jQuery that needs to display the content of a div depending on the options selected in a drop down

The drop down needs to pass numerical values into a calculator in order to work out a loan amount so when I added numerical values for the option value and corresponding div id the code doesnt work. If I change the the value and id to a word it works fine.

Is there a work around for this to get it working using the numerical values.

```
 <select name="apr" id="apr" class="loan-calculator__input" >                   
            <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="4.7" class="good">Good</option>
              <option value="14.9" class="fair">Fair</option>
              <option value="29.9" class="poor">Poor</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="4.7"  style="display:none;" class="rating" ><p>Good - </p>
</div>
<div id="14.9" style="display:none;"class="rating" ><p>Fair</p>
</div>
<div id="29.9"   style="display:none;" class="rating"><p>Poor  </p>
</div>

(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#apr').change(function(){
        $('.rating').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've created a jsfiddle to show the code - http://jsfiddle.net/nineseven/W37np/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the data attribute because you cannot use a number for an object id

```
   <div data-selectvalue="4.7"/>


   $("[data-selectvalue='"+$(this).val()+"']").show()
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct though. You can use numbers as id, just no decimals -> http://jsfiddle.net/W37np/19/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to grab the value of the selected option instead. The others are right too - your ids are not suitable. In the demo I've replaced them with dashes.

```
$('#' + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).show();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W37np/16/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to work when you use decimal ID's.
I probably wouldn't go with this workflow for displaying content.
But anyway, here you have a fiddle based on string id's:

http://jsfiddle.net/W37np/11/

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#apr').change(function(){
            $('.rating').hide();
            $('#' + $( "#apr option:selected" ).attr("value")).show();
        });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. Could I add a class to the options and generate the content by that instead?

Comment: The reason why I wouldn't use show/hide is because you may not know in advance how much content you will need to load into the DOM. This is why I would use `html()` or append() if you want to create a single page application (no entire page reload for every content update) and replace the content through an Ajax call to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because its been taken as an expression.. don't use numbers

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #14.9'

check the error console of the browser

Answer (score 0):

if want those value to those options value and you can change the div's id to different id say the class the option has then you can extract the class as follows and display it

```
$('#' + $( "#apr option:selected").attr('class')).show();
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/W37np/20/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#apr').change(function () {
                        $('.rating').hide();
                        var prefix = "div-";
                        $('#' + prefix + $("#apr option:selected").attr("value")).show();
                    });
                });


<select name="apr" id="apr" class="loan-calculator__input" >                
                <option value="-1">Select</option>
                  <option value="123" class="good">Good</option>
                  <option value="456" class="fair">Fair</option>
                  <option value="789" class="poor">Poor</option>
                </select>
              <div id="div-123"  style="display:none;" class="rating" ><p>Good - You are likely to have stable address and job history be on the electoral role and have plenty of good credit and no missed payments</p>
</div>
<div id="div-456" style="display:none;"class="rating" ><p>years carry a higher level of debt and perhaps missed the odd payment</p>
</div>
<div id="div-789"   style="display:none;" class="rating"><p>Poor – May have missed made late payments or have CCJs and have frequently moved jobs or not be on the electoral role </p>
</div>
```

Since Id does not accept numeric value. You can use a prefix on div tag.